# Worst case time complexity of the following function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

- V is sorted
- V.size() = N
- The function is initially called as searchNumOccurrence(V, k, 0, N-1)

```
    int searchNumOccurrence(vector<int> &V, int k, int start, int end) {
    if (start > end) return 0;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (V[mid] < k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
    if (V[mid] > k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1);
    return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 + searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this question?

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about - imagine your vector contains n copies of the exact same thing. The function, in that case, will keep splitting the array in half and searching both halves to count how many copies are there. And in doing so, it will visit each element of the array at least once (check this - do you see why?) So you're doing a constant amount of work per element in that case. Based on that, what do you think the runtime complexity is?

Answer (score 0):

The more same elemnts you have the less time you need to find them with binary search.
The slowest first search will happen when there is only one element you are looking for log(n)
In other cases finding the first element will happen in something like log(n/log(repsOfK))
But the more elements you are looking for means you will need to run function more times so it will be the sum
O(n) = Log(n/log(repsOfK)) + 2*log(n/(2*log(repsOfK-1))+...+2^n*log(n/(2^n*log(repsOfK-2^(n-1))))

You will have to find the maximum of this function to figure out your answer